# Value from useState is always initial value in map event callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, arcgis-js-api

I'm using `@esri/react-arcgis` to display a basic map. The goal is to send a request on click to find some data for the clicked area.

This is my map:

```
<Map
    onLoad={handleMapLoad}
    onFail={handleMapLoadFail}
    onClick={handleMapClick}
    ... // bunch of other properties (basemap, styles etc)
></Map>
```

My problem is, that when `onClick` fires (and `handleMapClick` gets called), the values from the component's `useState` is always the initial value.
It's defined like this: `const [mapViewReference, setMapViewReference] = useState(null);`.

It shouldn't always e null, because:

1. The `handleMapLoad` gets called in the beginning. It sets the following state: `setMapViewReference(view);` whereas `view` is a property I directly get from the esri library.
2. After that, I click on the map and the callback is executed
3. If I call `handleMapClick` from a dummy button the state/value will be correct.

Is this something that could be handled by `useCallback` or a different hook? I'm not sure if this is a problem with the esri library...

This is right before my `return` (functional component):

```
const handleMapClick = async event => {
    console.log(mapViewReference); // This is always null, unless I call the function manually from a dummy button
    const point = mapViewReference.toMap(event);
    const response = await featureLayerReference.queryFeatures({...});
};
```

Comment: `useCallback` is likely the right choice. Your initial state is being enclosed in the callback passed to `Map` and never updates to re-enclose a more current state value. Use `useCallback` to wrap your handler and pass the memoized callback down as a prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i used to have same issue with react-map-gl. i thing it's memo the onClick function when the component mount and doesn't update it when the map render on any state change. what i  did is to fire a `setState` when map click event tigger and do all my actions in `useEffect` when the event state change:

```
const [event,setEvent]= useState()

useEffect(()=>{
if(event){
   console.log(mapViewReference); // This is always null, unless I call the function 
     manually from a dummy button
    const point = mapViewReference.toMap(event);
    const response = await featureLayerReference.queryFeatures({...});
}
},[event])
```

and for the Map component :

```
<Map
    onLoad={handleMapLoad}
    onFail={handleMapLoadFail}
    onClick={setEvent}
    ... // bunch of other properties (basemap, styles etc)
></Map>
```

Comment: Seems kind of weird because the state works with `onLoad={handleMapLoad}`. Do you know why this acts that way?
But yeah, that fixed it.

Comment: yes i think if you navigate to the the module issue on github other people will have the issue. but i think there is still a way to access the state by using `setState` callback  like here : `setEvent(event=>{console.log(event)})`